# IBM domino designer , dblookup

Tags: xpages

I have question about using @DbLookup in xpages.
I have one simple nsf database looking like this :

```
Name             |          Values
TimeZones        | +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +10 +11 etc.
Countries        | Germany Ireland England Spain Slovakia Czech etc.
```

Problem is i dont know how to use @DbLookup to get only values of timezones or countries. I tried this and it did not work :

```
@DbLookup(@DbName(), "KeywordLookup", "TimeZones", "Values");
```

Where KeywordLookup is the name of my view.

But when i tried to use

```
@DbColumn(@DbName(),"KeywordLookup",1);
```

it works nice.  In my combobox i can see

```
TimeZones
Countries
```

Can anyone give me advice?

UPDATE #1:

my view "KeywordLookup" uses form "keywords" which looks like

```
Name:
-Type Text-

Values:
-Type Text-
```

And the view contains just two columns :

```
Name - mapped to Name
Values - mapped to Values
```

And i create document in notes and filled with :

```
Name :
Countries

Values : 
Germany
Ireland
Slovakia
etc.
```

Comment: please add more info about view structure

Comment: Did you sort the first column of your view? You must either sort it ascending or descending.

Comment: how to achieve it? I only in combobox item did following : Values > Add formula item > (option compute dynamically) : @DbLookup(@DbName(),"KeywordLookup","Countries","Values");

Comment: what @DbLookup(@DbName(), "KeywordLookup", "TimeZones", 2); returns, then? it should return Variant with content of Values field of "TimeZones" document.

Comment: Your code for the combobox is correct. Just go to the view "KeywordLookup" > right-click the first column in that view > Column Properties > go to second tab > select either one of the sort

Comment: it looks like it returns "" or null. I added simplevalue debugstart, then yourscript suggestion and another simplevalue debugend. Afterthen i can see only debugstart and debug and. No blank line. Just two lines with hardcoded values. But if i add @DbColumn script mentioned above i can see 4 lines with Countries and TimeZones between debugstart/debugend

Comment: @BaxterBXTR u were right. I quite dont get i because i thought it is quite like sql script and there is no need to sort something to find. But nice work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort your first columnn in that view. And just as a useful reminder, pick a more descriptive name for your fields. I'm afraid 'Name' or 'Values' are keywords in Domino environment. Same goes for 'Date', 'Key' etc.

Comment: ofc but this is just demo to understand this new enviroment. And if am i asking. Can u give me some hint how to get each value of "Values" field to one combobox item? My values ar all in same line. Thanks

Comment: Got it - just add newline separated records in properties of form. And edit existing database.

Comment: Don't use plain dblookup for that. Wrap it into a caching function - see my blog for an example